# Sum if key in one table matches key in another table - Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have a master table that contains all accounts with pre existing amounts for each account. I created a separate table where a user can select an account from the master table and specify the amount to adjust the pre existing amount by. How can I achieve this.

Steps:

- Lookup up the selected account in a new table
- Find the account from the master table
- Adjust the original amount by the user specified amount

Master table

| Account | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 000 |
| 3 | 15 000 |

New table

| Account | Adjustment Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 000 |

Results

| Account | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 000 |
| 3 | 15 000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Button(Adjust) and the following Macro, every time you press the button the amounts in New Table are added to the corresponding amounts in Master Table.
PS. If the Account not exist in the Master Table (like 32 in my New Table), don't worry, nothing happens ;)

[image: Master (before Adjust)]     [image: New Table]      [image: Master (After Adjust)]

```
Sub Button1_Click()
   i = 2
   While Sheet2.Cells(i, "A") > 0
      row_index = Application.Match(Sheet2.Cells(i, "A"), Sheet1.Columns("A"), False)
      If Not IsError(row_index) Then
         Sheet1.Cells(row_index, "B") = Sheet1.Cells(row_index, "B") + Sheet2.Cells(i, "B")
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: For inserting a Button: in Development Tab, click insert, and then under Form Controls, click Button. If you don't have Development Tab: On the File tab, go to Options > Customize Ribbon. Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer check box.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula as per given below screenshot.

```
=XLOOKUP(B4,$K$4:$K$5,$L$4:$L$5,0)+SUM(FILTER($G$4:$G$22,$F$4:$F$22=B4,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP want to update the original value in the original table. Sorry if not.

Comment: @Blackcat Then OP must need VBA.

Comment: That is correct. I want to update the value in the master table

Comment: @lancelot Then you have only one option to use VBA coding.